# Customizing QTableView grid style

Tags: c++, qt

I'm wondering several things. I have subclassed `QTableView` to make a custom table. I'd like to be able to do several things.

First of all, I wanted the selected cells not to all have the "selected" color (blue by default) but instead have a frame around the selected cells (just like in Excel). To do this, I've used the following (in my custom `QItemDelegate`):

```cpp
void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QModelIndex upIndex = index.sibling(index.row() - 1, index.column());
    QModelIndex downIndex = index.sibling(index.row() + 1, index.column());
    QModelIndex rightIndex = index.sibling(index.row(), index.column() + 1);
    QModelIndex leftIndex = index.sibling(index.row(), index.column() - 1);

    auto newOption = option;
    if (option.state.testFlag(QStyle::State_Selected))
    {
        painter->save();

        auto selIndexes = selM->selectedIndexes().toSet();
        painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::red, 5));
        if (!selIndexes.contains(rightIndex))
            painter->drawLine(option.rect.topRight(), option.rect.bottomRight());
        if (!selIndexes.contains(upIndex))
            painter->drawLine(option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.topRight());
        if (!selIndexes.contains(downIndex))
            painter->drawLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight());
        if (!selIndexes.contains(leftIndex))
            painter->drawLine(option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.bottomLeft());

        painter->restore();
        // newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Highlight, index.data(Qt::BackgroundRole).value<QColor>());
        newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Highlight, Qt::gray);
    }
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, newOption, index);
}
```

*This is probably not optimal, but I'd like to have something that works, before anything else.*

Now it seems to be working, but it unfortunately isn't automatically repainted. What happens when I select cells is the following:

[image: Incorrect]

Which is not what I'm looking for at all. I guess it's not being repainted because (1) The points inside the zone are still red and (2) If I resize my window, I get the following:

[image: Kind of correct]

Which is way closer to what I'm trying to achieve.

I've already tried to do this in my `QTableView`:

```cpp
// selModel is my selection model
connect(selModel, &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, [this]() {
    for(const auto & selected : selModel->selectedIndexes())
    {
        update(visualRect(selected));
        repaint(visualRect(selected));
    }
}
```

(Before, I actually used `setDirtyRegion` but it didn't work either, so I figured I'd do something more... brutal.)

Finally, I have another question: why do I get those weird red "small lines" in my cell corners? Even on the "kind of" correct screenshot I get these lines that I can't explain:

[image: Small lines]

Please suggest if you have any ideas for any of the issues.

Comment: First of all, your `paint()` needs to call the base class `paint`, ideally before you paint the frame.

Comment: Then, if you paint outside of the paint event's rect, you must expect weird effects. For a next step, to check that your logic is right, try painting the selection *inside* the fields and post a screenshot of that. (You can use `option.rect.adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1)`, for example.

Comment: Finally, mind the fact that the selection is painted with different rules than what your model's `data()` function returns for Background or Foreground.

Comment: @MartinHennings actually, it was called but I forgot to copy / paste it. About your second comment, I indeed know and that's exactly what I was looking for (unless I didn't understand your comment?) I have two other cases in paint(): if the item is active and if the item is neither active nor selected, and these work well (the background colours are the one I want)
That said, painting this other rectangle doesn't work (`(+2, +2, -2, -2)` doesn't either actually), would you happen to know why?

Comment: After doing some experiments, I found out that: I couldn't see my lines because the Gray Highlight brush would draw over them. If I set it to `Qt::transparent` then I can see my lines again. *Though*, it seems that only newly selected / deselected items get repainted. Others just stay as they were before (so I don't only the new bounds but also the old ones) *I checked that by assigning a random red or green color to the line, the lines in the selection that did not change always have the same color when the selection changes.*

Comment: See here: https://i.imgur.com/EUWPpQs.png 
Interesting detail: if I Alt + Tab in and out, it gets drawn to the right thing when the window shows up again.

Comment: The effect with Alt+Tab or window resizing is because these actions trigger a repaint of the complete window, including all widgets.

Comment: It appears that what was wrong was the `update(visualRect(selected))`, using `update(selected)` works... Would really like to know why, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be easily explained as follows.

Assume that the cell (0,0) is selected. Now the user selects the additional
cells (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1). Qt correctly repaints the additional 3 cells, that
became selected. But, it doesn't repaint the cell (0,0), as it was neither 
selected nor deselected. Of course for your desired behavior you still need to redraw this cell.

This can easily be achieved by just redrawing all indices of your current selection.

**MyDelegate.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QItemSelectionModel>

class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {

public:
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;

    void setSelectionModel(QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel);
private:
    QItemSelectionModel* mSelectionModel{ nullptr };
};
```

**MyDelegate.cpp**

```
#include "MyDelegate.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>

void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!mSelectionModel) return;
    auto newOption = option;
    auto normalText = newOption.palette.brush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::Text);
    newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::Highlight, QBrush(Qt::GlobalColor::blue, Qt::BrushStyle::NoBrush));
    newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::ColorGroup::Normal, QPalette::ColorRole::HighlightedText, normalText);
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, newOption, index);
    QModelIndex upIndex = index.sibling(index.row() - 1, index.column());
    QModelIndex downIndex = index.sibling(index.row() + 1, index.column());
    QModelIndex rightIndex = index.sibling(index.row(), index.column() + 1);
    QModelIndex leftIndex = index.sibling(index.row(), index.column() - 1);
    //auto newOption = option;
    //newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Highlight, Qt::transparent);
    if (option.state.testFlag(QStyle::State_Selected))
    {
        painter->save();
        painter->setClipRect(option.rect);
        auto selIndexes = mSelectionModel->selectedIndexes().toSet();
        painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::red, 5));
        if (!selIndexes.contains(rightIndex))
            painter->drawLine(option.rect.topRight(), option.rect.bottomRight());
        if (!selIndexes.contains(upIndex))
            painter->drawLine(option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.topRight());
        if (!selIndexes.contains(downIndex))
            painter->drawLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight());
        if (!selIndexes.contains(leftIndex))
            painter->drawLine(option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.bottomLeft());

        painter->restore();
    }
}

void MyDelegate::setSelectionModel(QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel)
{
    mSelectionModel=selectionModel;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include "MyDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto widget = new QTableView;
    QStandardItemModel model;
    model.setRowCount(10);
    model.setColumnCount(10);
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            model.setItem(i, j, new QStandardItem("Test"));
        }
    }
    auto selModel = new QItemSelectionModel;
    selModel->setModel(&model);
    widget->setModel(&model);
    widget->setSelectionModel(selModel);

    auto delegate = new MyDelegate;
    delegate->setSelectionModel(selModel);
    widget->setItemDelegate(delegate);
    // Ensures that also items are repainted, that where neither selected nor deselect, but will stay selected
    // This solutions eventually paints elements twice
    QObject::connect(selModel, &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, [widget,selModel](auto &selected, auto& deselected) {
        for (auto item : selModel->selectedIndexes()) {
            widget->update(item); 
        }
    });
    widget->show();
    app.exec();
}
```

As for the strange red line artifacts, you should paint the red line inside the allowed rectangle I guess. This is easily achieved by clipping to the item boundaries.

Comment: After some checking, it appeared that the artifacts were caused by the pen being 5px wide, and the Gray Highlight overlapping (actually hiding) most of the line, which resulted in... that. Thanks for your answer, I'm trying it.

Comment: @ThomasKowalski The lambda inside the connect is the important thing here. A QItemSelectionModel should already be created when you set the model to the view.

Comment: Sorry to contradict, but my initial constructor said was `selModel = selectionModel();` and then multiple lines later `connect(selModel, ...)`, so `selModel` would already have been initialized to something correct. What seems to have make it work here was the `widget->update(item)` instead of `update(visualRect(item))`. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Also, having `newOption.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Highlight, Qt::gray);` actually draws over our line (having `Qt::transparent` lets me see the line, `Qt::gray` does not), do you know how to avoid that?

Comment: @ThomasKowalski: So you don't want to have breaks in your red line across cell boundaries?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, but [this](https://i.imgur.com/b3j4AH9.png) is the expected behaviour (apart from the fact I'd like the background to be gray, *ignore red / green it was for testing*)

Comment: @ThomasKowalski: I changed my `MyDelegate.cpp` in order to fulfill your desired feature. (At least I think so)

Comment: Doesn't quite work unfortunately... The background is still white :/

Comment: Try again. It works for me. Maybe you need to include the current file I just posted. The point is that selected text is drawn white.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you!